# Magento 2: error 500 and issue with a Composer

Tags: magento2.2, composer

I have an error 500 "*site is currently unable to handle this request*"., and this is what logs are writing:

> [Wed Jul 25 07:21:16.343013 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 396] [client 176.125.35.8:44830] PHP Warning:  require_once(/opt/site/magento2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/site/magento2/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
>
> [Wed Jul 25 07:21:16.343052 2018] [php7:error] [pid 396] [client 176.125.35.8:44830] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/site/magento2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /opt/site/magento2/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

What I did:

```
rm -rf vendor/* 
composer install 
magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And here's autoload.php:

```
 <?php
 // autoload.php @generated by Composer
 require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
 return ComposerAutoloaderInit9a57ea70d7384ed87e1dc08bd2c8c9ab::getLoader();
```

Comment: Check the permissions are correct or not.

Comment: permissions for all files and directories in the root is 777